# MS Access VBA Dlookup on Yes/No field

Tags: vba, ms-access

I can't for the life of me work out what is wrong with this, but I'm not an Access/VBA developer normally..

I have a database table with about 20 fields, one of which is a Yes/No field. I want to extract the Yes/No value using DLookup, however am receiving the following error:

```
Run-time error '3075':
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Enabled'.
```

The code I am using it:

```
MsgBox (DLookup("Enabled", "Numbers", "ID = " & Me.cbxNumber.Value & ""))
```

Enabled is a Yes/No field
ID is a String field.

The above DLookup works absolutely fine for returning String values for other fields, so the last parameter with the search query, and the table field, should be fine. It is simply complaining about the return field ('Enabled') thinking it is a query.

The MsgBox element is also irrelevant, as I have tried assigning the result to an Integer and to a Boolean, and it's not complaining of a type mismatch which I would expect if this were the problematic part.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stated that ID is a string field.  If that is the case, try changing the DLookup to...

```
DLookup("[Enabled]", "Numbers", "ID = " & Chr(34) & Me.cbxNumber.Value & Chr(34))
```

If ID is a Long, then use this string...

```
DLookup("[Enabled]", "Numbers", "ID = " & Me.cbxNumber.Value)
```

Comment: This worked perfect - the square brackets fixed it, not that I really understand that element of the syntax. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine for me:

**Table:**

[image: Example table]

**Form:**

[image: Example form]

**Code:**

```
Private Sub Command30_Click()

    MsgBox (DLookup("Enabled", "Numbers", "ID = " & Me.cbxNumber.Value & ""))

End Sub
```

The messagebox displays 0 or -1 as required. Things to check:

Is your code in the forms module? Otherwise `Me.cbxNumber.Value` won't return anything.

What do you get if you run

```
debug.print Me.cbxNumber
```

from the OnClick of a button on the form?

Comment: Me.cbxNumber is definitely in scope because I'm using a DLookup with other fields in the first parameter and the same query in the third parameter fine. The debug prints out the ID correctly. The below solution fixed it; it was the square brackets missing, not that I really understand that element of the syntax!

Comment: Good to hear it's working now! It seems strange that the square brackets fixed it; I was under the impression they were only necessary when the field name contains a space (which "Enabled" obviously doesn't).

I didn't catch your note about ID being a string - if it is, I'm also surprised that your code with `"ID = " & Me.cbxNumber.Value & ""` as the third parameter works! A string must be enclosed in double quotes, so as suggested by Kevin Francis, it should be

`"ID = " & Chr(34) & Me.cbxNumber.Value & Chr(34)`

or

`"ID = """ & Me.cbxNumber.Value & """"`

using the double " to escape.